# Pesachim 115a – Syria or Sura?

Tags: maseches-pesachim

I'm learning now Pesachim 115a. On this page it reads:

> **בסוריא** עבדי כרב הונא
>
> In **Syria,** they acted in accordance with Rav Huna

This spelling is used in the [Oz veHadar edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=115&format=pdf), on [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2310.htm) and [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.115a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). [Soncino](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Pesachim.pdf), Sefaria translates it as *in Syria.* However, Artscroll (at least the first edition) and the [Steinsaltz commentary](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Steinsaltz_on_Pesachim.115a?lang=bi) use בסורא spelling in the translation meaning *in [Sura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sura_%28city%29),* the famous city in Babylonia. Actually the second one also makes sense, but I suppose it might be a typo. [Dikdukei Soferim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38517&st=&pgnum=365) doesn't mention these variants. Are there any commentators discussing this? Was it changed in later editions?

Comment: The latest digital Artscroll edition also has Sura

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Steinsaltz_on_Pesachim.115a.2?lang=bi

Comment: Rav Huna was Rosh yeshivat Sura ..https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43956&st=&pgnum=367&hilite=

Comment: Oz Vehadar has Suria as you said, but they note that manuscripts say Sura. I assume it's a mistake with the Vilna Shas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Hachi Garsinan](https://bavli.genizah.org), (or you can search the Hebrew terms [here](https://www.lieberman-institute.com/Category/213-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99) as well) or any other manuscript collection, in **all** (bar none) of the major written manuscripts that we have available (Munich 6, Munich 95, Columbia 294-295, Vatican 109b, Vatican 125, and many others, see [here](https://www.academia.edu/33974422/The_complete_manuscripts_of_the_Babylonian_Talmud) for more info), the correct reading is Sura.

Only some printed versions have the version of Suriya, which is mistaken.  Notably (h/t to commenters), Rav Huna was the Rabbi of Sura (see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43956&st=&pgnum=367&hilite=)), making it clear that that is the correct reading.

Dikdukei Sofrim may not have had any versions that said Suriya, and therefore did not comment on this.

---

**Edit:** Here are some of the images, because for some reason people are super-impressed by pictures of manuscripts, and then they upvote twice as much as they would have if you just tell them that you actually checked the manuscripts...

Munich 6:
[image]

JTS Rab. 1608:
[image]

Cambridge University Library T-S F 1(1).116:
[image]

I find it funny that they get smaller and smaller...

Comment: In an edition I found eventually among הגהות וציונים the following note: ב) בכת"י בסורא

Comment: It's true, that's what the kisvei yad say...

Comment: I'm also a manuscript fan, so I've checked the site you cited, and it's a great one! Although the chapters are in different order, but it's here in [MS München 95](http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00003409/images/index.html?id=00003409&seite=133&fip=193.174.98.30&nativeno=%2F&groesser=300%25). Fifth short row on the right side. For me it's hard to tell.

Comment: @kazi thanks. It's hard to see overall, but even if it said Suriyah, it wouldn't change my conclusion.